# Move method to another Java class, and call the method from the original class

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Dear valued program gurus!

I need help on moving a method to another Java class.

I am having a Java class called ProfileList.java containing the following code:

```
package dk.timeleft.versionone;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class ProfileList extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnGet;
    Button btnPost;
    TextView txtResult;

    public String url;
    public String postUrl;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_list);

        btnGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGet);
        btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPost);
        txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);


        btnGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                txtResult.setText("Retrieving GET-data");
                url = "https://kairosplanner.com/api/timeleft.php";
                try {
                    getResponse();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btnPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                txtResult.setText("Retrieving POST-data");

                postUrl = "https://kairosplanner.com/api/timeleft2.php/";
                RequestBody postBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("first_name", "Hans")
                        .add("last_name", "Schmidt")
                        .build();
                try {
                    postRequest(postUrl, postBody);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    void postRequest(String postUrl, RequestBody postBody) throws IOException {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(postUrl)
                .post(postBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                final String myResponse = response.body().string();

                ProfileList.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                            //txtString.setText("First Name: "+json.getJSONObject("data").getString("first_name") + "\nLast Name: " + json.getJSONObject("data").getString("last_name"));
                            txtResult.setText(json.toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }


    void getResponse() throws IOException {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                final String myResponse = response.body().string();

                ProfileList.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {

                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                            //txtString.setText("First Name: "+json.getJSONObject("data").getString("first_name") + "\nLast Name: " + json.getJSONObject("data").getString("last_name"));
                            txtResult.setText(json.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(ProfileList.this,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

    public class OkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
            builder.url(params[0]);
            Request request = builder.build();

            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                return response.body().string();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //txtString.setText(s);
        }
    }

}
```

This is working without any problems, but I'd like to have my code clean an neat.
I will be using the POST and GET functions (postRequest and getResponse methods) often, also in other Java classes, so it would be better, I guess, if those methods, including the OkHttpHandler class, to a separate Java class, e.g. ApiCommunicator.java, and call the methods from there.

I found a lot of information on how to refactor, but that just deletes the current ProfileList.java class.

I also tried just to copy the methods (postRequest, getResponse and OkHttpHandler to ApiCommunicator.java (and afterwards delete these methods from ProfileList.java), but that gives a few other problems, e.g. the .runOnUiThread runnable within the OnResponse method in postRequest and getResponse - those refer to ProfileList.this in stead of a dynamic Java class.

So my question is: how do I move a method from one class to another, and call the method from the original class?

BTW: I am using IntelliJ

I hope somebody can help me with this problem.

Comment: It's no problem to move the OkHttpHandler method to another class, but I am still having problems with moving the postRequest and getResponse methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:** Added `ApiCommunicatorListener` interface to `ApiCommunicator` that needs to be implemented by ProfileList activity to get the result back and assign it to txtResult.

You could create your ApiCommunicator class like so:

```
public class ApiCommunicator<T extends AppCompatActivity & ApiCommunicator.ApiCommunicatorListener> {

    private T activity;

    public ApiCommunicator(T activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void postRequest(String postUrl, RequestBody postBody) throws IOException {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(postUrl)
                .post(postBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                final String myResponse = response.body().string();

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                            activity.postRequestResult(json.toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

    public void getResponse() throws IOException {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                final String myResponse = response.body().string();

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                            activity.getResponseResult(json.toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

    public interface ApiCommunicatorListener {
        void postRequestResult(String result);
        void getResponseResult(String result);
    }
}
```

After that, you need to implement the interface in ProfileList activity like so:

```
public class ProfileList extends AppCompatActivity implements ApiCommunicator.ApiCommunicatorListener {
```

Then you're gonna add those two methods to ProfileList:

```
@Override
public void postRequestResult(String result) {
    txtResult.setText(result);
}

@Override
public void getResponseResult(String result) {
    txtResult.setText(result);
}
```

And finally use ApiCommunicator:

```
ApiCommunicator apiCommunicator = new ApiCommunicator<>(this);
apiCommunicator.postRequest(...);
apiCommunicator.getRequest(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But it still returns in errors, since txtResult is assigned in ProfileList.java. I came a bit further, and think I need to make a return call or something: In my OnClickListener (in ProfileList.java), I refer to getResponse, and getResponse gets response from the API. That response needs to get back to the OnClickListener, somehow. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @Kairos I edited my answer. Please accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks :)